# Is "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " color an indicator of something wrong?

Tags: java, android, sql

[image]

As you can see, the line of code that says "DROP TABLE IF EXIST " is not green, but orange. Why is this happening? Is it something ton worry about?

Comment: that's just the appearance or "theme" of the IDE. it's not a warning or anything of that sort.

Comment: I think this purely depends on the editor you are using. Does it work when you run your program?

Comment: Strings seem to be orange in your IDE theme.

Comment: Why does this question remind me of [XKCD's Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)?

Comment: If your using an IntelliJ IDE (Such as Android Studio) normal strings are green, however it detects SQL statement strings and shows them in orange instead.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be Android Studio. It looks like you just have the cursor on the String. The IDE highlights it for you.

But to be frank, dropping the table in onUpgrade() isn't a good solution because everytime the database version increments, the user loses their data.

Answer (score 1):

If you hover over the highlighted text you will see any error message that might exist. The appearance of various categories of things that IDEA communicates to you (orange background) is configurable via the settings; presumably you have not changed the default appearance.

As you know, the quoted text is not valid SQL, and the missing text comes from `Constants.TABLE_NAME`, but IDEA is not smart enough to know that.

So the answer is "don't worry about it".